# XML2PDF Throwing Exception while URL starts with /

Tags: python, css, xml, django, pdf

I got a Django HTML template with some harcoded CSS parts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"Arial";
    src: url(/static/fonts/Arial.ttf);
}
@font-face {
    font-family:"Arial_Black";
    src: url(/static/fonts/Arial_Black.ttf);
}
```

When I wrote the URL's in CSS prepended with '/' xml2pdf throwing this error below:

> Exception Type:   AttributeError
>
> Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

at line

/home/www/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xhtml2pdf-0.1b3-py2.7.egg/xhtml2pdf/util.py in **init**

```
line: 621. if self.mimetype.startswith('text'): ...
```

If I remove the '/' then xml2pdf begin to work but template unable to load font files.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem finally revealed it self as mime type problem when I dig into it.

I found the problem when I check all steps. In a step, xml2pdf try to find mime type of the file, and it looks like Python 2.7.6 has no mime type description for **.ttf** file

```
>>> from mimetypes import MimeTypes
>>> import urllib 
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('static/fonts/Arial.ttf')
>>> mime = MimeTypes()
>>> mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
>>> print mime_type
(None, None)
>>> url = urllib.pathname2url('wsgi.py')
>>> mime_type = mime.guess_type(url)
>>> print mime_type
('text/x-python', None)
```

I append the lines below to function to correct problem:

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/font-ttf', '.ttf')
```